# Как правильно указать в скобках даты правления императора?

Tags: пунктуация, даты

Если в тексте слова "правление" нет.

Нашла прецеденты:

> Константин Великий (306 — 337 гг. правление)

и

> Константин I Великий (Флавий Валерий Константин), святой
>   равноапостольный, император Римский (306—337).

До сих пор видела только у римских пап даты в скобках, означающие период папства; у всех прочих даты через тире без отбивок - годы рождения и смерти.

Так что же с императорами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Пётр I Алексе́евич**, прозванный **Вели́кий** (30 мая [9 июня] 1672 года — 28 января [8 февраля] 1725 года) — последний царь всея Руси (с 1682 года) и первый Император Всероссийский (с 1721 года).

**Никола́й II Алекса́ндрович** (6 [18] мая 1868, Царское Село — 17 июля 1918, Екатеринбург) — Император Всероссийский, Царь Польский и Великий Князь Финляндский (20 октября [1 ноября] 1894 — 2 [15] марта 1917).

Святой император Константин (306-337), получивший от Церкви именование Равноапостольный, а во всемирной истории наименованный Великим, был сыном цезаря Констанция Хлора (305-306), правившего странами Галлией и Британией.
...
 Отец его не преследовал христиан в управляемых им странах, в то время, как во всей остальной Римской империи христиане подвергались жестоким гонениям со стороны императоров Диоклитиана (284-305), его соправителя Максимиана Галерия (305-311) — на Востоке и императора Максимиана Геркула (284-305) — на Западе. После смерти Констанция Хлора сын его Константии в 306 году был провозглашен войсками императором Галлии и Британии.
[**Святой император Константин Великий**](http://www.patriarchia.ru/db/text/912224.html)

Текст у Вас явно специфический, особенный. Если конкретно речь идет только о годах правления, тогда в скобках можно указать годы "императорства", а годы жизни не указывать.

Comment: Ога, принято! Красочные примеры - я их все проверила. Только *Диоклитиан* частая ошибка и у автора. Он ДИОКЛ**Е**ТИАН!!!

Comment: Ну, это официальный сайт Московского Патриархата. Я конкретно по персоналиям не проверяла. Важным ведь было другое: оформление дат.

Answer (score 1):

Указать титул, что бы не путали с годами рождения и смерти.
К примеру: (Император Страны N 1ХХХ - 1ХХХ).

Точнее даже так: имя (титул дата-дата). 
Вася Пупкин (Председатель колхоза "Красная заря" 1927-1938)

Comment: Титул указан. Император. Тогда можно не волноваться, что годы жизни и годы правления кто-то перепутает?